# In Autofac C# Resolve, how to pass parameter to constructor

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac, .net-4.8

I have an Interface with the class whose constructor takes Autofac IContainer as a parameter. How I can pass this parameter at a time to resolve this class. I have tried to use new NamedParameter but getting an error

### Class

```
public class AppAmbientState : IAppAmbientState
{
    public IContainer ServiceContainer { get; }

    public AppAmbientState(
        IContainer container
        )
    {
        ServiceContainer = container;
    }
}
```

### In the console app

```
  var appAmbientState = buildContainer.Resolve<IAppAmbientState>(new NamedParameter("IContainer", "buildContainer"));
```

### Registration to container

```
 public static IContainer Configure()
    {
        ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterType<AppAmbientState>().As<IAppAmbientState>().SingleInstance();
```

### error

```
DependencyResolutionException: None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'App.ConsoleHost.AmbientState.AppAmbientState' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
Cannot resolve parameter 'Autofac.IContainer container' of constructor 'Void .ctor(Autofac.IContainer)'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting error because named argument is `container` but `IContainer` is type of this argument.
You can change your code to:

```
var appAmbientState = buildContainer.Resolve<IAppAmbientState>(new NamedParameter("container", buildContainer));
```

and it will work